# VisualStudio 2017 - Debugger skips over code when using step into

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

What could cause VS 2017's debugger to skip stepping in to code? I've verified that the build is set to `Debug` and that the project's `Properties->Build->Optimize code` is unchecked. I've tried deleting all the source and output files from my computer and checked it out again from TFS, yet the issue still remains. I've tried logging in as a different account and uninstalling/reinstalling VS and neither resolved the issue. The debugger works fine if I set manual breakpoints and will hit them in portions it would otherwise not step into, but using `Step into` will often skip portions of my own code for no discernible reason.

**Edit**

So disabling `Just My Code` fixed it which I dont understand at all the code is in the same solution, although in two projects/assemblies. So I guess my answer would now be, why does VisualStudio think the middle/end of a method is not "My Code"

Comment: The first reason I can think of is that the source code needs to be recompiled. Another reason is that the source code is not part of the build due to something like the file not being part of the project or the use of preprocessor directives is causing the source code to be skipped by the compiler.

Comment: I've cleaned and rebuilt the project several times, manually deleted the source and build directories. The source code is part of a build, it will step the start of a method and then skip the middle/end. As I mentioned if I manually set a breakpoint in the code it will work as expected. There are not preprocessor directives telling the debugger to skip called methods.

Answer (score 1):

> why does VisualStudio think the middle/end of a method is not "My Code"

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Debugger.General);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true) document:

> **Enable Just My Code**
>
> The debugger displays and steps into user code
> ("My Code") only, ignoring **system code** and **other code that is
> optimized** or that **does not have debugging symbols**.

Even if all the code is in the same solution, although in two projects/assemblies, you still need make sure if it is optimized and have debugging symbols.

**Note**: Don't miss copy .PDB file to the compiling directory.